# How to get a PC member's attention to comment on or review my submission?

Tags: phd, conference, peer-review

I have submitted a thesis abstract to PhD consortium and my submission was accepted.
I just noticed that one of the program committee is well known professor on my thesis area. *Actually, many of the paper citations contain his name*. Now, I believe he was not a reviewer for my submission (I know because I didn't get critical -deep- questions about my work) but I don't have hard evidence for this.

what is the right way to get his attention to comment on my work?
is it adequate to email him my submission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PC member may be a professor, but I promise, they are human just like you and me. In your place, I'd find out the email address of professor and write a polite email making your case that

- you are both researchers in the same field
- you noticed the professor is actively participating in that special PhD consortium
- your submission to that consortium was accepted
- you have been following/citing that professor's work, but be very brief and direct about it! you're a researcher, but neither fan nor worshipper!
- you care for a meeting at the conference to which that consortium is associated
- you appreciate that professor's opinion

Or, if you really just care for feedback on that submission, you can flat out ask for an opinion on your submission.

These worked quite well for me. Also, direct approaches during coffee breaks are opportunities as well, but (T)PC members often have closed meetings during those so you would have to take your chances ...

But seriously, experts in their research areas care for the work of other researchers ... or you needn't care for their opinion.

Comment: I've added in the response to indicate that you have been following or citing that professor's work. If you are able to say, "I'm currently using your XYZ method from the Intl. Conference on Gidgets and Widgets to solve interesting problem" then you will likely grab that person's attention.

Comment: @Irwin has the right answer. Irwin, why not post it in its own right?